# How to get container interaction details inside a cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, containers, kubectl, weave, cni

let's say I have certain containers running in a cluster like kube-apiserver, dns-controller
and let's say these two containers are communicating with each other, so I want to capture these interactions in a tabular format like [from]-[to] or in any other JSON structure for all the containers running in the cluster.
Is it possible to get these details using Kubernetes python client?

Used weavescope (Service discovery tool) to get the same information through some API, but I want to explore other methods, tried looking into the kubectl commands, but was not useful. I'm currently going through Container Network Interface (CNI) concepts.

can someone suggest an approach that can be tried or any existing way to achieve this?

Comment: when you say interaction what details are you looking for ? Packets details? Tracing ?

Comment: I'm trying to capture the communication links between containers , just the name of the containers is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for just visualisation same as **weavescope** you can explore the : [spekt8](https://github.com/spekt8/spekt8) or Kiali with Istio(service mesh, it would be too much)

If you want to use just **K8s API** and trying visualization this might could help you: [kubesurveyor](https://github.com/viralpoetry/kubesurveyor)

**Kubesurveyor** is an open-source and **python** based option, which is not required to run on the K8s cluster.

Another one with K8s API : https://github.com/benc-uk/kubeview